# if inside a while loop causing trouble

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

I'm having trouble on the last part of my program.
The code substracts an array `p[j]` with an input number `nStevilo` and then puts in into absolute. It then compares the result with a substraction of an array `p[j++]`.
The code should go through the array and find the smallest value and append it into `najblizjeStevilo`, but for some reason it doesn't work?

```
while (j < 20){
        if (abs(p[j] - nStevilo) < abs(p[j++] - nStevilo)){
            najblizjeStevilo = p[j];
        }
    }
```

The array includes 20 prime numbers, starting from 2 (2, 3, 5, 7, 11...), so `p[0]` = 2, `p[1]` = 3...

Comment: What does this line means : **"The code should go through the array and find the smallest value and append it into najblizjeStevilo"** . Does it means that you have to sum up all minimum values in each iteration ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Problems like "why doesn't my code work?" must come with a [mcve] and a precise error description. Otherwise they are considered off-topic and usually downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 4):

You are relying on sequencing that isn't there. You assume that `j` will be incremented only after the left hand side of the comparison has finished running. There is no such guarantee by the C++ standard. So your program has undefined behavior on account of modifying `j` and reading it in one full expression without proper sequencing.

Rather than being clever and writing `j++` opt instead to be explicit in how things need to be sequenced:

```
while (j < 20){
        if (abs(p[j] - nStevilo) < abs(p[j + 1] - nStevilo)){
            ++j;
            najblizjeStevilo = p[j];
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are still adding to `najblizjeStevilo` the value of `j + 1`. Not what he was looking for.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel - He was looking for code that can be reasoned about with well defined semantics. This is leaps and bounds ahead of any "complexed fix" you think you provided.

Comment: Maybe `if (abs(p[j+1] - nStevilo) < abs(p[j] - nStevilo)); ++j;` is what the OP is waiting for. The fact that what OP wants to do is unclear implies that such solutions should be avoided even if it works

Comment: @Damien - Writing the increment on the right is a funny way of showing you expect it on the left. I trust Occam's razor enough to pinpoint the apparent fallacy. Now that the OP knows what part of their code had no hope of being well-defined, they can carry on in their journey and figure it if the algorithm is correct to boot.